# Gremlin : GroupBy vertices , having count > 1

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am using TITAN 0.4, and gremlin for traversals.
My requirement is to identify duplicate vertices in graph, and to merge those.
There are > 15 M vertices in graph.

```
gremlin> g.V.has('domain').groupBy{it.domain}{it.id}.cap

==>{google.com=[4], yahoo.com=[16, 24, 20]}
```

I am able to group the vertices, but I need only those domains(vertices) which exists more than once.

In the above example, I need to return only `==>{yahoo.com=[16, 24, 20]}`
The key "domain" is indexed, if that makes any difference.

Please help me here

Answer (score 2):

Consider use of `groupCount` rather than `groupBy` to save a step of counting up ids in your collected list:

```
g.V.has('domain').groupCount(it.domain}.cap.next().findAll{it.value>1}
```

I suppose this is cheaper as well on a larger traversal as you are just maintaining a counter rather than lists of identifiers.

Comment: This solution works well in my dev environment, but in production, I have 10M + vertices , in which this fails to run throwing below exception:-
gremlin> g.V.has('ip_address').groupCount{it.ip_address}.cap.next().findAll{it.value>1}
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(ip_address <> null)]. For better performance, use indexes

Comment: that's not an exception - merely a warning that you are iterating all vertices.  i suspect that your exception is an `OutOfMemoryException` perhaps?  either way, that's the nature of your query - it has to iterate all vertices to find the "domain" property to `groupCount` on them.  if you have to do that then and your graph is large then (1) throw more memory at the problem or (2) use titan-hadoop or (3) restructure your graph in some way to allow a use of an index.

Comment: Yes I am getting outofmemory exception
the grouping step is failing, because of TemporaryStorageException
gremlin> g.V.has('domain').groupCount{it.domain}.cap.next().findAll{it.value>1}
WARN com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(domain <> null)]. For better performance, use indexes
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryStorageException: Temporary failure in storage backend
Also I am using TITAN standard Index in Key "domain"
g.makeKey("domain").dataType(String.class).indexed("standard", Vertex.class).make();

Comment: You may have created an index on 'domain' but your query doesn't make use of it.  Your query is simply looking for any vertex with the 'domain' key which requires a scan of all vertices.  A query like `g.V.has('domain','google.com')` would use the index as it is looking for find a specific 'domain' in that index.  The solution to your problem remains as being one of the three options I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but did you try below to force the index?

`g.V.hasNot('domain', null).groupBy{it.domain}{it.id}.cap`